# How do I merge the creation of a single file in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge

I have an SVN revision which creates two files (and makes some other changes), but I only want to merge the creation of one of the files into my branch. If the file already existed, I could do:

```
svn merge -c479 ../branch/dirs/file dirs/file
```

However, it doesn't, and I get

```
svn: E155010: Path '/stuff/dirs/file' does not exist
```

I can merge the entire revision, then revert the file creation, but that feels hacky and probably messes up the mergeinfo. What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using the `svn copy` command.

```
svn copy -r479 ../branch/dirs/file dirs/file
```

This copies the file as it was when it was created, along with the history of being created by the person who created it. In this respect, it's slightly different to a merge, but it seems effectively what you want.